# form won't submit if fields are empty in angular 4

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I working on angular 4 project. I am using smart table and form in it.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <nb-card>
      <nb-card-header>Default Inputs</nb-card-header>
      <nb-card-body >
        <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "addNewStudent(f)" >
        <div class="row full-name-inputs">
          <div class="col-sm-6 input-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="data.firstName" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 input-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" name="lastName" [(ngModel)]="data.lastName" [required]="false"/>
          </div >
            <div class="col-sm-6 input-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="ID" class="form-control" name="id"[(ngModel)]="data.id" [required]=false />
          </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <button type="cancel" class="btn ">Cancel</button>

       </form>
      </nb-card-body>
    </nb-card>
      </div>
</div>
```

on edit button of table the form is open and shows the whole data of that row in that form, similar form button will be open on add new data in which the data should be added but if I enter only one data and submit it it does not add it it requires all fields.

the add function is as follow

```
addNewStudent(f: NgForm)
    {
    console.log(f.value);
    if(this.isAddPage)
       {
       this.service.addNewEnquiry(f.value);
       console.log("addenquiry");
       }
       else{
        this.service.editEnquiry(f.value);
       console.log("editenquiry");
       }
        this.router.navigate(['pages/dashboard1']);

    }
```

the addNewEnquiry function in service is as follows

```
 addNewEnquiry(data) 
{

    this.af.list('/enquirydata/').push(data);

}
```

when I enter all fields it added it to the firebase but when I doesn't fill all fields it shows me error.

any help?

Comment: @rrd any help??

Comment: Try adding ngNativeValidate to the form tag?

Comment: @rrd its not working

Comment: You mentioned that when you partially fill the form you're getting an error. What error is it showing you?

Comment: ERROR Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'enquirydata.lastName'

Comment: if I enter an lastname it will show error for id and so on.

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some data checking before pushing. Something like a filter removing undefined/null values in data.

Comment: where can u give any solution